# Php Sort and count occurencies of array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have this array in the beginning

```
Array
(
    [0] => FRUIT
    [1] => MONKEY
    [2] => MONKEY
    [3] => MONKEY
    [4] => CANNABIS
)
```

with `array_count_values()` I get this

```
Array
(
    [FRUIT] => 1
    [MONKEY] => 3
    [CANNABIS] => 1
)
```

but actually I would like to sort it like here:

MONKEY 3 
FRUIT 1
CANNABIS 1 (when the Integer is the same it doesn't have to get extra sorted alphabetic, that's not necessary)

I looked around, but couldn't find something appropriate.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why don't you just sort the array after using that function?

Comment: Hello, what do you mean exactly?

Comment: He means use [rsort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rsort.php)

Comment: Oh, thank you very much for this answer as well :) It actually isn't exactly the thing I was searching for, but I could have used it, so thanks again :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`asort` is what you want :) 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php

> asort — Sort an array and maintain index association

Basically sorts an associative array by value.

```
<?php
$words = [
   'FRUIT',
   'MONKEY',
   'MONKEY',
   'MONKEY',
   'CANNABIS',
];

// Count each occurrence
$counts = array_count_values($words);

// Sort the counts in descending order
arsort($counts);

// Display the results
var_dump($counts);
```

Produces:

```
Array
(
    [MONKEY] => 3
    [FRUIT] => 1
    [CANNABIS] => 1
)
```

Comment: Ahhh thank you very much! For two things actually xd 1. Now I know for what var_dump() is for and I've also found arsort in another Thread here earlier but var_dump was the thing I was missing! Thank you to everyone who responded so quick! :)

Comment: But wait, could you please also tell me, how I can then get the key name and the value from var_dump or the above result?

Comment: Ahh okay, I just have to continue to use the array normally, thank you again :)

Comment: Yes :) var_dump only prints out the results for debugging. The array is just a normal array.